# How to make custom filter for a only json objects keys not for values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and was trying to filter nested json data basically what i am trying to do is trying to make a custom filter for only json objects keys not for values. i want to show all the keys with value that i will place in a search field.

Comment: In coding what you have tried upto now?

Comment: i have no idea about how to filter the nested json keys. i have search allot of stuff on google but i didn't saw any similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better idea to iterate through the array instead of object. Transform your object into array and then simply print the values what do you need using the filter:

JavaScript

```
[...]

var arr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      arr.push(obj[i]);
   }
}

[...]
```

HTML

```
[...]

<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="search.a" />
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in arr | filter:search">
   {{item.a}}
   {{item.b}}
   {{item.c}}
</div>

[...]
```

**EDIT**

Related to the picture you posted you need something like this.

HTML

```
[...]

<div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="search.id" />
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
   {{item.index}}
   {{item.id}}
</div>

[...]
```

Comment: i am not looking for values. i am totally concern about the keys. look at this picture. you will get what exactly i am asking [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2nkkkjp/8)

Comment: @user1821483 Well, my HTML example absolutely fits on your data structure from the picture - what's more, you have the array already so the solution is simplier because you don't need making any transformation from object to array :) Try to read the [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for better understanding.

Comment: @user1821483 I made an edit related to your picture.

Comment: yeah. but the doc explain only about the values. i don't know how to search in keys.

Comment: @user1821483 You don't have keys in your example.

Comment: its all about keys. the picture is clear explanation of searching in keys. let me explain a little but more about it. for example i have a json and it have multiple json objects and every json object have a 'id' property. i want to filter all the propert with 'id'. i will place 'id' in search filed and all the keys 'id' with value will be filter.

Comment: @user1821483 Sure. In this case transform the object into array of objects, the key add as value in each object in your new array. Then use the filter as usual. But, this is not the case of data structure you have posted.